# Infinite series $\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{k\sin(kx)}{k^2+a^2}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation, contour-integration, residue-calculus

How can I evaluate the infinite series
$$\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{k\sin(kx)}{k^2+a^2}$$
using the residue theorem?

My approach was to use the function
$$f(z)=\frac{z\sin(zx)}{z^2+a^2}\frac{\pi}{\tan(\pi z)}$$
integrated about a circle centered at the origin, but I kept coming up with the wrong answer.

Comment: Didn't you forget two residues at $z^2+a^2=0$?

Comment: @A.Γ. I don't think so, I remember including those in my computation. From this, I ended up concluding that
$$\text{Res} f(z)_{z\in\mathbb Z}+\text{Res} f(z)_{z=\pm ai}=0$$

Comment: Did you prove that the integral over the circles vanishes as $R\to+\infty$? Compare with [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2583836/paradoxical-result-by-residue-theorem)

Answer (score 3):

I think it is more efficient to exploit the Fourier series of $e^{-ax}$ over $(0,2\pi)$.
We have
$$ \int_{0}^{2\pi}e^{-ax}\sin(k x)\,dx = \frac{k}{k^2+a^2}(1-e^{-2a\pi})$$
$$ \int_{0}^{2\pi}e^{-ax}\cos(k x)\,dx = \frac{a}{k^2+a^2}(1-e^{-2a\pi})$$
hence
$$ \sum_{k\geq 1}\frac{k\sin(kx)}{k^2+a^2}=\frac{\pi}{2}\cdot\frac{e^{-ax}-e^{-2a\pi+ax}}{1-e^{-2a\pi}}=\frac{\pi \sinh(\pi a-ax)}{2\sinh(\pi a)}. $$